# How To Get Thread NID(Native ID) in java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-dump

> "remoting-jmx client-thread-4" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000f86b000 nid=0x20e0 >waiting on condition [0x000000000b82e000]
>     java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
>     at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>     - parking to wait for  <0x00000000ebd8bcc0> (a >java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
>     at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
>     at >java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQue>ue.java:460)
>     at >java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.j>ava:359)
>     at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:942)
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>       at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Here in this thread dump, we have thread Nid. This Nid how can i get it from a thread in java code.

Comment: You can't. There is no API for it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/rednaxelafx/843622) which shows how to obtain the NID if you can include `lombok.jar`from [project lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) and `sa-jdi.jar` from the JDK in your app.